# Approximations for $\sin \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is in degrees?

Tags: trigonometry

Are there any approximations for $\sin \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is in degrees? without transforming it into radians.

I'm asking because this is what I understood from this question in Gelfand's Trigonometry.

**Question:** The table above shows that $\sin \alpha$ is approximately equal to $\alpha - \alpha^3/6$ if $\alpha$ is a small angle measured in radians. Write the corresponding approximation for $\sin D$, where $D$ is a small angle measured in degrees. Your ap-proximation should be an expression in the variable $D$. Then check your expression for $D=1$.

Comment: You'd have to write degrees in radians. Degrees are arbitrary units based on a Babylonian system. I doubt there is much specific mathematical machinery that approximates them without being based on properties radian measure.

Comment: You've quoted a passage from a book without the referenced "table above". The exercise just asks you to convert the $D$ in degrees to an equivalent value in radians in order to obtain the correct (small angle) approximation to $\sin D$.  Perhaps you are saying, I don't want to follow the instructions of this exercise.  However you leave Readers guessing at what you do want to do.

Comment: Well, I thought of that, but I felt it was cheating or was not the intended solution, so I came here to hear expert opinions.

Comment: @hardmath The table is just about doing some computations, namely checking the $\alpha - \alpha^3/120$ approximation. I didn't think it would be important.

Comment: The exercise is pretty clearly stated.  Also, note that $D=1$ is a small angle (in degrees) while $\alpha = 1$ (in radians) is not small enough to give a particularly accurate approximation.  One radian is $180/\pi$ degrees.

Comment: Anyways, If the correct solution was just transforming D into radians by multiplying it by $\pi/180$ then I am totally fine.